# Reverse relation ToManyField Tastypie

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I have two resources (Tastypie), one of which has a `ToManyField` field:

```
class SongResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Song.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'song'
        authorization = Authorization()



class AlbumResource(ModelResource):
    songs = fields.ToManyField('core.api.SongResource', 'songs', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'album'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

So when I access my PlaylistResource I see something like this :

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/playlist/1/?format=json` Here is the response I get :

```
{
"created_in": "2012-06-24T22:57:01+00:00",
"id": "1",
"number_of_plays": 0,
"playlist_slug": "my-first-playlist",
"playlist_title": "my first playlist",
"resource_uri": "/api/v1/playlist/1/",
"songs": [{
    "genre": "Progressive metal",
    "id": "2",
    "length": "04:19",
    "number_of_plays": 0,
    "price": 0.0,
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/song/2/",
    "song_slug": "leyla-2008",
    "song_title": "Leyla",
    "song_url": "http://www.amazon.s3.com/prologue",
    "thumbnail": "http://almacosta.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/bob_marley.jpg?w=250",
    "year": 2008
}, {
    "genre": "Progressive metal",
    "id": "3",
    "length": "3.26",
    "number_of_plays": 0,
    "price": 0.0,
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/song/3/",
    "song_slug": "yazamadim-2008",
    "song_title": "Yazamadim",
    "song_url": "http://www.amazon.s3.com/prologue",
    "thumbnail": "http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/3215/14so8.jpg",
    "year": 2008
}]
```

}

Now I want to access the album or artist of each song, so I added

```
album = fields.ForeignKey('core.api.AlbumResource','album')
```

to my `SongResource` but I get this error

```
{
"error_message": "'Song' object has no attribute 'album'",
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 406, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1058, in get_detail\n    bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 654, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 709, in dehydrate\n    m2m_dehydrated.append(self.dehydrate_related(m2m_bundle, m2m_resource))\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 514, in dehydrate_related\n    return related_resource.full_dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 654, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 621, in dehydrate\n    foreign_obj = getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute)\n\nAttributeError: 'Song' object has no attribute 'album'\n"
```

}

Is there any trick that allows me to get the reverse data?

**EDIT**
Here are my Song and Album models (same order as I have in the models.py file)

```
class Song(models.Model):

    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null = True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True, null = True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    thumbnail = models.URLField(default = '/media/thumbnail.png')
    song_url = models.URLField()
    number_of_plays = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Number of plays')
    price = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
    song_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.song_title

class Album(models.Model):

    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    release_year = models.IntegerField('Release Year')
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    album_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.album_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/album/%s' % self.album_slug
```

Comment: Post your models. Does `Song` actually have an `album` attribute?

Comment: No it doesn't have an album attribute. Wouldn't it be duplicate?

Comment: Yes, but that's why you're getting that error. You told it to look for an attribute on `Song` called `album` which obviously doesn't exist. You should try a `ToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey` and tell it the attribute is `album_set`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked fine ! However, it returns the URI of the album, how can I make it return the object itself?

Comment: I made my comment an answer, so we can keep StackOverflow clean. I explained how to show the full resource, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `ToManyField` instead of ForeignKey and tell it the attribute is `album_set`. To get the full resource to be included, specify `full=True`.